# Model class data Access the all view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

Hi I have two view controller main view had multiple textfields am saving the textfield data into model class, working fine but my aim i can use model class data into multiple view controller.
thes is my model class

```
   class PersonalDetails
    {
        private var _email:String?

        var email:String! {
            get {
                return _email
            } set {
                if newValue != nil && newValue != ""{
                    self._email = newValue
                }
            }
        }
        init(email:String?) {
            self._email = email

        }

    in mainview controller 

    var UserDetails   = [PersonalDetails]();
    Above viewdidload 

         UserDetails.append(PersonalDetails.init(email: signup_TxtEmailId.text ,fullName:signup_TxtFullName.text, phoneNumber: getNewMobileString))

inside button action I'm performing this one
```

how to access the my model class data from main view controller to other view controller(multipleviewcontroller),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Create a variable **UserDetails** in next view controller also like you did in your main view controller. Then pass your UserDetails array in main view controller to UserDetails array in next view controller

```
let vc = NextViewController()
vc.UserDetails = self.UserDetails
```

**Approach 2**

Save the [PersonalDetails] array as globally accessible by all view controllers, using singleton. To create a singleton, add a swift file to your project and paste this code in that file :-

```
class Singleton {
    static let shared = Singleton()
    var UserDetails = [PersonalDetails]()
}
```

Then in your main view controller, add this after you finish appending all the PersonalDetails object to UserDetails array :-

```
Singleton.shared.UserDetails = self.UserDetails
```

So from any view controllers, any time you can call that array by using this line :-

```
Singleton.shared.UserDetails
```

So UserDetails will be saved in the Singleton class till you close the app. Also anytime you can change the value of that array also